# How do i stop my terminal from opening vim files whenever i open up the terminal application

Tags: vim, terminal

I was trying to add a flutter app to my firebase project using the flutter fire cli. I was prompted to add a path to my .zshrc file which i did and saved properly. However it didn't work and now whenever I open up my terminal, it automatically opens up the zshrcexport file. I have attached a screenshot of the first thing I see whenever I open up my terminal.[image]

And below is another screenshot of my zshrc file[image]

Comment: What's in your PATH?

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass i just added a new screenshot showing what's in my path

Comment: You have the problem right there in the first 2 lines...

Answer (score 0):

Correct the first two lines.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin"
```